# JVM creation fails for NetBeans application with custom memory settings

Tags: java, memory, netbeans, jvm

I have a NetBeans framework (v7.2) application that needs a fair amount of memory when it starts. I had configured that in a configuration file in the usual way, where the relevant chunk of the config file reads like this:

```
# options used by the launcher by default, can be overridden by explicit
# command line switches
# default_options=-J-Xms512m -J-Xmx1024m
default_options=--branding myapp -J-Xms1G -J-Xmx3G
# for development purposes you may wish to append: -J-Dnetbeans.logger.console=true -J-ea

# default location of JDK/JRE, can be overridden by using --jdkhome <dir> switch
#jdkhome="/path/to/jdk"
```

This application runs fine on my development machine, but when I attempt to run it on another machine that does not have the JDK installed (only the JRE) I get a message that "JVM creation failed." I have found, through trial and error, that I can get around this error in one of two ways: either by reducing the memory requirements (I've found that `-J-Xms512m -J-Xmx1024m` works), or by explicitly setting the value of `jdkhome` in the config file to point to the location of the JRE. Since I need the RAM, I can't very well reduce the memory requirement. So I think I'm stuck with the second solution, but it makes no sense to me. Can anyone explain why requesting "large" amounts of memory at startup requires `jdkhome` to be set explicitly, but smaller amounts of memory seem not to have this requirement?

Comment: Looks like you have a 32 bit Vm in your path (you can easily check that with `java -version`. And do you really need one GB stack? I'd check with `jvisualvm` and reduce to a reasonable size.

Comment: The Heap size is bounded by Java Rule - initial heap size
Larger of 1/64th of the machine's physical memory on the machine or some reasonable minimum.

maximum heap size
Smaller of 1/4th of the physical memory or 1GB. ALSO it matters "what JVM detects the machine to be - CLIENT OR SERVER" Look here : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/vm/server-class.html

Comment: Could be a 32-bit VM on the one machine, or a 32-bit OS. You also can't allocate more memory than on the machine either, so if the machine doesn't have 3G then that would be a problem too.

Comment: I think @GyroGearless hit the nail on the head. The problem appears to stem from java.com installing 32bit or 64bit JVMs based on the browser you're using. Then when the NetBeans .exe starts it appears to find the 32bit version first and tries to use that. Explicitly setting the path obviously gets around this. Gyro, you should add an answer so I can upvote you.